# when i install cucmber into my project, i got this error, how to resolve this?

Tags: cucumber

An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.java, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.pde.launching,3.10.300.v20230129-1906.
Error reading signed content:C:\Users\ASLAMS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile6818576436838212010.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: C:\Users\ASLAMS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile6818576436838212010.jar

tried to install cucumber

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.